# How to change username of SAML authentication in Cognito

Tags: oauth, amazon-cognito

The username of a user created with SAML authentication will be {provider name}_{email}, can it be a sub value as you normally create it?

Comment: Hi @hamham. Welcome to stackoverflow. You haven't asked a question. You really need to ask a clear question so that other people know the precise issue that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks @lemming. I edited this post more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a user authenticated using SAML IdP, the username is managed by Cognito service in the format {provider name}_{email}. It is not editable and cannot be changed.